# How to properly install steambp

Tags: grub2, software-installation, scripts, themes

I'm new at Ubuntu and very eager to learn the ropes. I´m having a bit difficulty working the Terminal though. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

I am trying to install this awesome GRUB modification https://github.com/LegendaryBibo/Steam-Big-Picture-Grub-Theme/blob/master/README.md

Now it tells me to install it by running the install.sh through root in terminal, I've managed to get root, but I have no idea how I go about installing the script. If anyone could tell me the exact way to do so that'd be great, the Readme is a bit lacking in information for starting people. I did install the font needed though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands to install it from the directory it is saved:

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip Steam-Big-Picture-Grub-Theme-master.zip
sudo -i
cd ~/Downloads/Steam-Big-Picture-Grub-Theme-master/
chmod 755 install.sh
./install.sh
```

(it requires root).

The install script will install files to a new directory "SteamBP" in one of these directories, in the 1st one it finds: /grub /boot/grub /boot/grub2 and the grub version on the system needs to be at least 1.98.

There are 3 settings in the install.sh you can edit prior to installing:

```
Theme_Name="SteamBP"            
Theme_Definition_File="theme.txt"
Theme_Resolution="any"
```

The 1st notice that all is going well will be a question regarding the resolution if the last option is set to "any".

---

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much man, so different from Windows it takes a bit getting used to but I was succesfull thus far :D http://prntscr.com/9it75u

Comment: I am going to clean up comments ;-) feel free to do so too :+

Comment: Done :) This thread can be locked and marked as solved!